# DOM Rerenders When It's Not Necessary in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've build an application in AngularJS and it works as intended, however, I'm having performance issues because it's rerendering the DOM for my chat (which uses ng-repeat) anytime any variable on the scope changes.

I've been able to reproduce this in <kbd>[this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0NoKc65BNSXd5NeYSQlM)</kbd>.

Why is it doing this and how can I get it to only rerender the message log when `$scope.messages` is changed? Furthermore, how can I get it to only update the element that is new or different when changes are made to `$scope.messages`?

<kbd>[View on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0NoKc65BNSXd5NeYSQlM)</kbd>

index.html:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.4.6"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>How can I prevent Angular from rerendering the chat log everytime another var on the scope is changed?</p>
    <p>Furthermore, how can I make it only add the new value when a message is added rather than rerendering the entire message log?</p>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="msg in messages track by $index">
        {{ msg.name }}: <span ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(msg.message)"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <button ng-click="incRandomVar()">Update Unrelated Variable {{ randomVar }}</button>
    <button ng-click="addMessage()">Add new message</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.randomVar = 1;
  $scope.incRandomVar = function () {
    $scope.randomVar += 1;
  };

  $scope.messages = [
    {name: "John", message: "Hello world, give <a href=\"http://google.com\">Google</a> a try!"},
    {name: "World", message: "Google? What's that?"},
    {name: "World", message: "Wahooa, this looks cool!"},
    {name: "John", message: "They call it a \"Search Engine\", you can find anything on there!"}
  ];

  $scope.addMessage = function () {
    $scope.messages.push({name: "System", message: "This is a system message"});
  };

  $scope.trustAsHtml = function (message) {
    console.log('Rerendering message:', message);
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(message);
  }
});
```

**Edit:** It appears to be caused by the calling of a function (`trustAsHtml`) within' the ngRepeat. However, I can't render the HTML without calling that... How could I go about this without taking the performance hit?

Comment: Demo works fine... how many items are you loading?

Comment: Demo doesn't work fine, if you look at the console it's rendering the messages 3 times each initially and anytime any value on the scope it rerenders the entire list.

Comment: that's how digests work ... best not to call functions in the view when they aren't needed

Comment: How else do I bind the HTML then?

Comment: add the `trustAsHtml` to each message object instead of calling a function for each